# Sorting TStringList: error in Delphi and Android

Tags: android, sorting, delphi

I created a CustomSort for a list with TStringLinst. On Windows works fine, but on Android `List` object is sent as `nil` to the `CompareDatesReverse` function. In the documentation there is no any difference between the operating systems to this function.
Is there any different handling for the CustomSort function on Android?

**Parameter `List = nil` in the `CompareDatesReverse` function on Android => Error: Exception class Segmentation fault (11)**

```
   TObjAux = class(TObject)
      FileAge: TDateTime;
      Path: String;
   end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   function CompareDatesReverse(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
   var d1, d2: TDateTime;
   begin
      d1 := TObjAux(List.Objects[Index1]).FileAge;  // List = Nil on Android
      d2 := TObjAux(List.Objects[Index2]).FileAge;
      if d1 > d2 then
         Result := -1
      else if d1 < d2 then
         Result := 1
      else
         Result := 0;
   end;
var
   LList: TStringDynArray;
   i: Integer;
   fls: TStringList;
   vTmp: String;
   ObjAux: TObjAux;
begin
   fls := TStringList.Create;
   fls.Clear;

   vTmp  := TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
   LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(vTmp);

   for i := 0 to Length(LList) - 1 do begin
      ObjAux      := TObjAux.Create;
      ObjAux.Path := LList[i];
      FileAge(LList[i], ObjAux.FileAge);
      fls.AddObject(FloatToStr(ObjAux.FileAge), ObjAux);
   end;

   if fls.Count > 0 then fls.CustomSort(@CompareDatesReverse);

   fls.DisposeOf;
end;
```

Comment: That's pretty darn yucky. Why don't you use a `TList<T>` with each item being a record containing the data. Then you don't need to pointlessly convert file age to a string.

Comment: But as for the error,  the use of the @ operator is where to start. Remove that, and then fix the compiler error. Which will involve not using a nested function. Don't use the @ operator with procedures and functions. It just stops the compiler from saving you. I'll close this against the standard duplicate next.

Comment: 1) You're right about duplicate question; 2) Retraining the nesting of the `CompareDatesReverse` function works on Android and Windows, thanks! 3) However, I didn't understand how to remove `@` in this case. I read your documentation of the other issue, but even after a few hours, I still couldn't modify my code to work as you suggested (without `@`) 4) Good `TList` idea and I'll use it as soon as I can solve the main problem. Can you help me solve it?

Comment: Forget it! It works without `@` now. I will implement the `TList` issue which is cool! Thank you.